# In magento how to add multiple recipients to 'Send Emails to' field in Email Options under contact Us

Tags: magento, email

In my magento site i need to send the contact email to more than one recipient.How to add additional email id in **Send Emails to** field in Email options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to System > Configuration > Contacts and add your Email-id’s in comma delimit in “Send Emails To” field (eg: test@gmail.com,user1@gmail.com.user2@gmail.com)

Copy file from  **code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php** into your local like **code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php** or make your `Custom Module` depending upon your requirement.

In **postAction** you should find a few lines of code that look like this:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
 ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
 ->sendTransactional(
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
 null,
 array('data' => $postObject)
 );

if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 throw new Exception();
 }
```

Change it to below:

```
$recipients = explode(",",Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT));
 foreach($recipients as $recipient){
 $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
 ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
 ->sendTransactional(
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
 $recipient,
 null,
 array('data' => $postObject)
 );

 if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 throw new Exception();
 }
 }
```

Comment: If i have updated the code and entered the two mail id's with , it throws out the error as please enter a valid mail id.@vikram

Comment: @RamaPriya what you can do is if your making your custom module you can change the validation type for email-id to <input id="contacts_email_recipient_email" name="groups[email][fields][recipient_email][value]" value="" class="input-text" type="text">
This will allow multiple email-id

Comment: can you please explain it briefly.where i need to update this code? @Vikram

Comment: You can develop your won module for this requirement and in admin end where you specify the input field avoid email validation class and then in your controller for postAction you can get store config data something like this
`code`Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT);`code`

Comment: Best way you can use class validate-emails in your input type which will validate your comma separated email address.

Comment: @RamaPriya if it was useful to you pls upvote the answer for other users

Comment: Hi actually i have updated the quick contact extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/freequickcontact-mageworld.html which is used to get feedback from customers.This module using the email id which we have given in send email to option in admin.Now my requirement is to add two email id to send feedback form details to 2 recepients.i have no idea about how to implement it in my extension.if you can,please guide me.@Vikram

Comment: You should never edit core files directly, this will make updating Magento version remove what you have changed! You could instead make a patch for this. However in this case just sending the email twice with different recipients would suffice! So don't modify core file(s)!!

Comment: @OZZIE, that was just an example shows here. None the less, no one is curious to edit core files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it through admin section of magento if is it your mandatory requirement then you need to override the magento contact module for customization.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it.I must need it.I am in need to send mail to two recipients @Saurabh

Comment: @RamaPriya try this http://iamvikram.com/magento-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-contact-us-form/